# POSTing server-side events to Facebook Marketing API

Tags: facebook, facebook-marketing-api

Is it possible to fire events from a server-sided application to Facebook's Marketing API?

Their developer platforms only allow for pixel (websites), mobile, windows, & facebook canvas apps. The mobile/Windows applications require a store ID as well.

Basically what we're trying to do is fire events from our web service when we receive a post to our webhooks for a conversion from our calltrackingmetrics integration. CTM posts to our webhook, then our endpoint will fire the event into Facebook's Marketing API.

I was thinking about using a javascript library in python to load up Pixel & fire the events.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to fire s2s pixel fires by make https call like this

```
https://www.facebook.com/tr?id={pixel id#}&ev=Purchase&ud[external_id]=external_id1&noscript=1
```

the event name is purchase, and parameter is external_id. you can add more parameter there.

But Facebook is not encouraging s2s pixel fires, because it is hard to match the user. you will need to use advanced matching to send PII data like email, user name align with the pixel fire to get matched.

Comment: can you explain the external_id parameter, where is that derived from?